# How to read and process contents of conf file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, config, file-read

I have a `td-agent.conf` file which has below contents:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/thingtrax/Documents/ThingTraxDevice/pi/logs/zigbee/TX-S2-MGS-001_health.json
  pos_file /home/thingtrax/Documents/ThingTraxDevice/pi/logs/zigbee/TX-S2-MGS-001_health.json.pos
  format json
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  tag health001
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/thingtrax/Documents/ThingTraxDevice/pi/logs/zigbee/TX-S2-MGS-001_cycle.json
  pos_file /home/thingtrax/Documents/ThingTraxDevice/pi/logs/zigbee/TX-S2-MGS-001_cycle.json.pos
  format json
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  tag cycle001
</source>

<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    hostname ${hostname}
    Customer "TYS"
    Version "V2"
  </record>
</filter>

<filter *E9E2*>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    EquipmentId "MC05"
  </record>
</filter>

<filter *005*>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    EquipmentId "MC13"
  </record>
</filter>

<filter *006*>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    EquipmentId "MC01"
  </record>
</filter>
```

From the above file contents, I only want to get the data between `<filter>...</filter>` such that in the output I should have `dict` containing following data:

```
[
  {
    "device": "E9E2"
    "equipment": "MC05",
  },
  {
    "device": "005"
    "equipment": "MC13",
  },
  {
    "device": "006"
    "equipment": "MC01",
  }

]
```

For this, I first though of converting it into json but looks like it cannot be done. I also tired using `re` to extract the substring but that seems also not working. Can anyone please suggest some good ideas. THanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with any libraries that may be able to parse custom file formats, like this which looks a bit like a mix of xml and whitespace seperated key-value data...

However, I attempted to find a regex that can extract the data you want [(link to demo)](https://regexr.com/6156e):

```
(<filter \*)(\w+)(\*>.*?)(EquipmentId ")(\w+)(".*?<\/filter>)
```

- You *must* pass the `DOTALL` flag (to include `\n` being matched by `.`)
- The 2nd and 5th capture groups contain the device and equipment data.

Here it is in python, worked well for me with the contents of the file you've included in the question (Python 3.7.8)

```py
import re

text = """file contents here...."""

pat = re.compile(r'(<filter \*)(\w+)(\*>.*?)(EquipmentId ")(\w+)(".*?<\/filter>)',
      re.DOTALL)

parsed = []
for match in re.finditer(pat, text):
    parsed.append({"device": match.group(2),
                    "equipment": match.group(5)})
print(parsed)
```

I've read (and generally agree) that using regex to parse complicated grammars and file formats etc is tricky / a bad idea, but this task had specific enough requirements that it seemed possible without much unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

*Hint: You can consider it as an HTML task and thus can make use of BeautifulSoup package*

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('td-agent.conf','r') as f:
  text=f.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
results=[]
for tags in soup.find_all(True):
  if 'filter' ==tags.name:
    for elements in tags.record.string.splitlines():
      if 'EquipmentId' in elements:
        results.append({"device":list(tags.attrs.keys())[0].replace('*',''),"equipment":elements.split(' ')[-1].replace('"','')})

print(results)
```

```py
print(results)
Output: [{'device': 'e9e2', 'equipment': 'MC05'}, {'device': '005', 'equipment': 'MC13'}, {'device': '006', 'equipment': 'MC01'}]
```